# Доступ к Git через консоль выдает ошибку Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

ОС - Windows 7.
У меня установлен Source Tree, и есть учетка на Bitbucket.
В Source Tree генерирую SSH ключи, сохраняю публичный ключ `test.pub` и приватный ключ `test_private.ppk` в папке .ssh, приватный ключ добавляю в Pageant.
Копирую сгенерированный ssh-ключ, сохраняю на Битбакете. 
Через интерфейс Source Tree коммиты и пуши проходят без проблем, но когда пробую сделать всё то же самое через консоль, то нет доступа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**UPD**
[image]

В чём тут проблема?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте выполнить команду `ssh` с флагом `-v` или `-v -v` для разных уровней отладки.

Comment: В вопрос добавлен апдейт.

Comment: Попробуйте `ssh-add keyFileName`

Comment: Получаю ошибку Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: то есть вы ввели `ssh-add test.pub` ? если да, то попробуйте `ssh-agent -s`

Comment: вот такой вот результат http://i.imgur.com/9KxzLU4.png

Comment: Теперь снова ssh-add раз агент запущен

Comment: Похожая ошибка бывает, когда права доступа к файлу ключа "слишком открытые". Обычно спасает что-то в духе `chmod 600 /path/to/key`.

Answer (score 2):

> приватный ключ test_private.ppk

судя по суффиксу имени файла (`.ppk`), это, скорее всего, приватный ключ в собственном формате программы *putty*.

с помощью той же программы, которая вам сгенерировала этот файл с ключом (возможно, это была и не *putty*, а какая-то её обёртка/замена), вам надо экспортировать этот ключ из этого файла **в формате *openssh***. вот какое-то [руководство](http://computing.kiae.ru/user-support/user-manual.html#ssh-keys.windows-to-unix) для ориентира.

сохранить файл надо под именем `id_rsa` (если ключ был создан с использованием алгоритма [*rsa*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA), это выбор по умолчанию) или `id_dsa` (если ключ был создан с использование алгоритма [*dsa*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSA)) в каталоге `c:\\users\таня\.ssh\`.

будьте внимательны: если файл с таким именем в этом каталоге уже есть, лучше не перезаписывать файл, а предварительно переименовать существующий (на случай, если старый файл вам вдруг понадобится).

после этого, по идее, программа `ssh` сможет использовать этот новый ключ.

Comment: Может лучше вместо переименования в `id_rsa` сделать `ssh-add`... Просто у одного человека может быть множество ключей для разных серверов...

Comment: @ReinRaus, я не против, но описание того, что сначала надо запустить ssh-agent (он ведь вряд ли запускается в *ms/windows* поверх всех процессов), потом выполнить *ssh-add* — всё это очень сильно удлиннило бы ответ. если у вас есть время и желание — напишите более правильный и точный вариант ответа.

Comment: Да я хотел точечными выстрелами в комментариях выяснить суть проблемы и закрыть как дубликат к своему вопросу :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, кстати, для полной академичности не помешает, наверно, упомянуть про то, что файл с ключом [можно указывать в `~/.ssh/config`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11251797/4827341).

Comment: @ReinRaus, если действительно дубликат, так закрывайте, конечно.

Comment: Нет, это не дубликат. Скорее всего Вы правы, что ключи в каком-то специфичном формате.